# "local variable 's' referenced before assignment" error. How do I fix?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list that takes in numbers and removes all the old numbers in the list and returns s the result, but it keeps on giving me the error "local variable 's' referenced before assignment" How do I fix it?

```
def purify(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item%2 != 0:
            lst.remove(item)
    s.append(lst)
    s = []
    return s
```

Comment: This won't work. Do not modify lists while iterating over them. Copy the list and operate on the copy.

Comment: If you are modifying `lst` directly, why not just return `lst`?  You probably either want to initialize `s` to a copy of `lst` at the top of the function and then `remove` from `s`, or just return `lst`.  Also, I'd bet you actually want `s.extend(lst)`, not `append`.

Comment: You're trying to add to `s` before you create it. Have you used assignment before? The [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: Why do you want to return a list containing a single list?

Comment: exactly what the error says... code reads line by line in this case, and s is defined after you append to s. that's like writing before you get a pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not remove items while iterating, because the list should not be changed when using iterators (this is what you do with "in").

```
def purify(lst):
    s = []
    for item in lst:
        if item%2 == 0:
            s += [item]  
    return s
```

btw: This can be done very fast with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
...
def purify(lst):
     indices = np.where(np.mod(lst,2) == 0)
     return np.array(lst)[indices]
```

Comment: I understand but why did you put the [] around  item?

Comment: `s.append(item)` would be more typical than `s += [item]`, which creates two new lists

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign s to empty list first and then append.

```
   def purify(lst):
        for item in lst:
            if item%2 != 0:
                lst.remove(item)
        s = []
        s.append(lst)

        return s
```

As @jonrsharpe  suggested, don't remove the item while iterating over list. The good approach is using the **list comprehension**:

```
[i for i in lst if i%2!=0]
```

Comment: Or just `return [lst]` - but note that there is an issue with modifying `lst`.

Comment: That's a great attempt at spelling my username!

Comment: Sorry about that mate. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear why you want to return a list containing a single list. Why not just return the "purified" list?

```
def purify(lst):
    return [item for item in lst if item % 2 == 0]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Demo:

```
>>> purify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[2, 4]
```

---

For more flexibility, you could also make a version where you pass your own rule:

```
def purify(lst, rule):
    return [item for item in lst if rule(item)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> purify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lambda i: i % 2)
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your life with filter:

```
filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(5))
```